How do memory barriers achieve thread-safety?
In C#10 in a Nutshell, Joseph Albahari writes:

A memory barrier is a “fence”
through which the effects of reordering and caching cannot penetrate.


This applies not just to locks but to all synchronization constructs.
So, if your use of a signaling construct, for instance, ensures that
just one thread reads/writes a variable at a time, you don’t need to
lock. Hence, the following code is thread-safe without locking around
x

while giving this example:
var signal = new ManualResetEvent (false);
int x = 0;
new Thread (() => { x++; signal.Set(); }).Start();
signal.WaitOne();
Console.WriteLine (x); // 1 (always)

x++ isn't supposed to be thread-safe (this question).
What I get from the above quote is that x++ is made thread-safe by doing this implicitly in code:
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
x++;
Thread.MemoryBarrier();

My questions is:

How does a memory barrier really achieve thread-safety by just preventing reordering and caching?

Where exactly would all the implicit MemoryBarriers() be placed in the code sample?



A memory barrier does not achieve thread safety. A memory barrier ensures that all memory writes that happened before the barrier are reflected in the memory. That means, they cannot be stored at a register, or in a cache, or the compiler cannot reorder them to be after the barrier.

A single instruction is never 'thread safe' or 'not thread safe'. It's a matter of how memory is accessed across multiple threads. There are also no magic or 'implicit' memory barriers placed here, signal.WaitOne requires a memory barrier to work and that's the only place you need one.
The author writes that this use is thread safe because at no point is the same memory accessed by multiple threads at the same time, and you're isolated from strange caching or ordering behaviour by the memory barrier.

@Cubic so the main point here is really that nothing is reordered/cached?

@BurakSerdar that was my understanding. Just don't understand the implication from the quote.


How does a memory barrier really achieve thread-safety by just preventing reordering and caching?

In Joseph Albahari's example, the implicit memory barriers don't achieve thread-safety by themselves. They are part of a greater mechanism, that also includes signaling. Remove either the barriers or the signaling, and you are left with a buggy mechanism. In order to get the desirable thread-safety, both components should coexist. The signaling ensures that one thread will wait until the other sends the signal that is has done incrementing the x. The memory barrier ensures that the compiler/Jitter/processor will not try to optimize the operation by reordering instructions and moving them from one side of the barrier to the other. Signaling is about threads, and barriers are about memory access.

Where exactly would all the implicit MemoryBarriers() be placed in the code sample?

There are two barriers.

One is placed before the signal.Set();, to prevent the compiler/Jitter/processor from reordering the x++ instructions, and moving them after the signal.Set();.
Another one is placed after the signal.WaitOne();, to prevent the compiler/Jitter/processor from reordering the reading of x (in the Console.WriteLine(x);), and moving it before the signal.WaitOne();.


so in essence it's all about preventing reordering?

@tinmanjk yes, it's mainly about reordering. A barrier also prevents the C# compiler from doing some "clever" optimizations, like reading (caching) a variable once and then using the same cached value forever. The C# compiler can do this in some very simple cases, that are featured frequently in books but occur rarely in practice. This means that people frequently get away by writing incorrect code (code that accesses shared memory without signaling nor barriers) because C# usually doesn't punish such code (until it does).

@tinmanjk borrowing the terminology of a recent GitHub issue: "A fence has optimization-suppressing effects."
